# how to preload images when a previous page function is executed on nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to preload images located in the public/assets/images directory in Next.js 13.(and images are dynamically allocated by map() method. so they are not imported in page component file) I want the images to be preloaded when a function on the previous page is executed (even before rendering). This is to ensure that the images are displayed instantly on the actual page where they are used.

It seems that using priority or placeholder attributes does not achieve the desired behavior. I want the images to be displayed as quickly as if the user had already downloaded them. How can I implement this?

I've tried  preload tags in the  component, but not working properly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.